# How to get the parent Id of the child automatically

Tags: python, oop, class, object

To be more clear on what i need, here is an example:
I have two boxes having 2 items each.
And, I want the item to be defined by it's own id and it's box_id.
I want the box_id to be global, because it will be used in the other methods of the Box class.

I don't want to explicitly set the parent id for the child, but i want it to get inherited automatically.

I tried this:

`file>> getid.py`

```
 class Box():
    id = 0
    def __init__(self,id):
        Box.id = id

    def __get__(self):
        return Box.id

    class Item():
        def __init__(self,id):
            self.id = id
            self.box_id = Box.id
        def __get__(self):
            return self.id,Box.id
```

I use this in another file as:

```
   from getid import *
   box1 = Box(1)
   box2 = Box(2)       

   In: box1.id
   Out: 2
```

For box1 call the class Box and pass the id as 1. 
And checked before again calling the Box for box2, the output of `box1.id` was 1.
But after calling the Box the output of `box1.id` changes to 2.

Can anyone please explain why I get the output here as 2, But what I expect is 1.

Comment: Contrary to what you say, `Item` isn't a subclass of `Box`

Comment: Also, could you expand a little on what you're actually trying to achieve with this

Comment: Item is indented, doesn't it make it a sub-class?

Comment: The term "subclass" means that A inherits from B, not that it's nested inside it.

Comment: We would be better able to help you if you explained the problem you're trying to solve with this construct.

Comment: @NPE I hope that the example defined well explains my problem. I need to have a id for an item to find where it has came from.

Comment: You're looking for the term _inner class_

Comment: Why does box need an id then? And why do you change box's id whenever you create a new box instance. Please explain carefully what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: To your latest edit: I already explained on my answer why you get 2 instead of 1.

Comment: @Mahi I need to change the box id, when ever i create a new box with some items. The Item doesn't know the box_id. But, I want the items to be put in different boxes and get the box_id of the item. How do i do this?

Comment: With the help of `parent`. I added an example code to the end of my answer.

Comment: @Mahi But how to do it without `parent` with the same structure defined in the question, because i need to use the `parent` box_id in other methods of the class Box.

Comment: @Alaissham I still don't get your problem. If you want to use parent's id in `Item` class' methods, you just do `self.parent.id` instead of `self.box_id`. If you need to use the box's id in `Box` class' methods, you do `self.id`. There's no better way of doing it, you need a parent.

Comment: Give me an example of the method (what is it supposed to do, which class is it in, etc) and I'll show you an example code. Then you can use it the same way for rest of your methods.

Comment: @Mahi The problem is not just id, I have to get certain attributes of the box like color, size, price for a given item in box, that is say 2 boxes has 5 pencils each and each pencil has an id. Defined an item pencil at any point, the code should return me the pencil id and it's box id. While init the pencil, i don't have the box id. But still i want to put the pencils in different boxes. If, I use self.box_id, I'm not able to pass the box_id to the item_id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20442/discussion-between-mahi-and-alaissham)

Comment: @Mahi I have found a way to do this, How to open this question again?

Comment: You can't afaik. You could do a whole new Q&A instead, if you really think the answer is worth it. I'm on mobile atm, but I'm eager to hear your way of doing it later.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that items are contained within a box does not mean that the `Item` *class* needs to be nested within the `Box` *class*:

Here is a very simple structure that does what you're asking:

```
class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, box_id):
        self.box_id = box_id

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, box, item_id):
        self.box = box
        self.item_id = item_id

box1 = Box(1)

box2 = Box(2)
item1 = Item(box2, 1)
item2 = Item(box2, 2)
```

(I've renamed the IDs so it is clear which is which.)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: If, I have to pass box2 as a variable, i don't need this at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's kinda hard to understand what you're trying to achieve from your post, but I'll try to give you examples on what I think you're trying to do.

Let's begin by focusing on only `Box`-class, and ignore the `Item` for now.
Here's what you have:

```
class Box():
    id = 0
    def __init__(self,id):
        Box.id = id

    def __get__(self):
        return Box.id
```

The `__get__` method is useless, simply don't use it here, you don't need it.
Now what we notice, is you set `Box.id = 0`, this means that you can call `print(Box.id)` and it will print `0`.
You can also init a new box instance, and you can call `print(box_instance.id)`, which will also print `0` as expected.

However, in your `__init__` method, you change `Box.id`, instead of the instance's own id, is this what you meant to do? Here's a quick example on what will happen with your code:

```
In: Box.id
Out: 0

a = Box(1)

In: a.id
Out: 1
In: Box.id
Out: 1

b = Box(2)

In: b.id
Out: 2
In: a.id
Out: 2
In: Box.id
Out: 2
```

As you can notice here (or test yourself), when initializing new `Box` object, it change's `Box` class' id, and not the id of the instance.
This way every instance's id changes if you init a new `Box` -instance.
This is caused cause it's not actually the id of the instance, but it's the id of `Box`.

If this is the behavior you want, feel free to use it (you still don't need `__get__`), but if you want each Box to have their unique id, use `self` instead of box.

```
class Box:
    id = 0 # This is Box class' id, it's not even necessary to define it
    def __init__(self, id): # This will be each instance's unique id
        self.id = id #self.id means the instance's unique id
```

---

Now that we got the `Box` pretty much done, we can start working on the `Item`.
I'm quite unsure of what you're trying to achieve with this, but taking a look at your code, it seems like you're actually trying to give each item an unique id (which is a good idea), and then you want to give them `box_id` which is simply `Box.id`, the class' id itself?
This doesn't make any sense to me.

What I ACTUALLY think you're trying to achieve: Insert items into boxes, and this way you want item to know it's "parent" box's id. It could be done as following:

```
class Item: #Notice how inheriting is not needed at all!!
    def __init__(self, id, parent):
        self.id = id
        self.parent = parent
        # I prefer calling it parent, call it what ever you want, box works too
```

Now what I'd also suggest, is:

1. Inside `Box.__init__()`, define a list `self.items = []`
2. Inside `Item.__init__()`, append `self` to parent's items. `self.parent.items.append(self)`

This way your items know the box they're in, and boxes know which items are in them.

---

**Edit:** A short example code on how to use the parent:

```
box1 = Box(1) #box1 has id of 1
box2 = Box(2) #box2 has id of 2
item1 = Item(3, box1) #item1 has id of 3, parent box1
item2 = Item(4, box2) #item2 has id of 4, parent box2
item3 = Item(5, box1) #item3 has id of 5, parent box1

In: item1.id
Out: 3
In: item1.parent.id
Out: 1
In: item2.id
Out: 4
In: item2.parent.id
Out: 2
In: item3.id
Out: 5
In: item3.parent.id
Out: 1
In: item3.parent == item1.parent
Out: True
```

As we see here, item can directly call it's parent's methods and use it's attributes.
This way you can have multiple items in a box, (`item1` and `item3` both have same parent) and each of those items' `parent` attribute points to the box.

Basically `item1.parent == box1` so `item1.parent.id` is what you called `item.box_id` in your code.

Comment: How do I know the parent. In the actual problem, i don't know the parent of the Item, I want the program to inherit it's parent id from the program. I did it, but it gets to the latest defined parent. To say in terms of your code, I exactly want the output of `a.id` to be 1.

Comment: You will need to pass the parent as a parameter - there's no better way of doing this. Why are you against it?